# C++ library across different compilers

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, abi

I'm writing a C++ library using MinGW (4.8.0 dw2 posix). This library is used in another C++ project that use another compiler( in this case msvc ).

Refering to [this](http://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html) I was redesign my C++ library. There are two things that I don't know how can I do:

1. Can I use namespaces?
2. I noticed that time_t on MinGW is 32 bit and in msvc is 64 bit. What Can I do?

**1)**

Does this broke the ABI:

```
// Window.h

// MYLIB_API defined as __declspec( dllexports )
// MYLIB_CALL defined as __stdcall

namespace mylib {

class Window {
public:
  virtual void MYLIB_CALL destroy() = 0;
  virtual void MYLIB_CALL setTitle(const char* title) = 0;
  virtual const char* MYLIB_CALL getTitle() = 0;

  void operator delete(void* p) {
    if (p) {
      Window* w = static_cast<Window*>(p);
      w->destroy();
    }
  }
};

} // mylib

extern "C" MYLIB_API mylib::Window* MYLIB_CALL CreateWindow(const char* title);
```

**2**

How can I be sure that foundamental types are the same accross different compiler. For example in this case `time_t` is defined as `unsigned long` on MinGW and `__int64' on msvc. What can I do?

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using? Is it going to be 2013?

Comment: @JohnBandela Can be one between 2010, 2012 or 2013. We can choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my library cppcomponents at https://github.com/jbandela/cppcomponents

This is tested with Visual C++ 2013 (Previous versions did not have enough c++11 support) and mingw gcc 4.7+ on windows. It is a header only library released under the boost license. This allows you to use c++11 features like std::string, vector, tuple, pair, time_point across the compilers. I would be happy to answer any questions you have regarding how to use it for your particular case.

Here is an example for your case

First define the class in Window.h

```
#include <cppcomponents/cppcomponents.hpp>

namespace mylib{

    struct IWindow :cppcomponents::define_interface<
        cppcomponents::uuid<0x0d02ac9a, 0x4188, 0x48fc, 0x8054, 0xafe7252ec188 >>
    {
        std::string getTitle();
        void setTitle(std::string new_title);

        CPPCOMPONENTS_CONSTRUCT(IWindow, getTitle, setTitle);

    };

    inline std::string WindowID(){ return "windowlibdll!Window"; }
    typedef cppcomponents::runtime_class<WindowID, cppcomponents::object_interfaces<IWindow>> Window_t;
    typedef cppcomponents::use_runtime_class<Window_t> Window;

}
```

Then implement the class in WindowImp.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"


struct ImplementWindow:cppcomponents::implement_runtime_class<ImplementWindow,mylib::Window_t>
{
    std::string title_;
    ImplementWindow(){}
    std::string getTitle(){
        return title_;
    }
    void setTitle(std::string new_title){
        title_ = new_title;
    }

};

CPPCOMPONENTS_DEFINE_FACTORY()
```

Finally Use the code in UseWindow.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    mylib::Window w;
    w.setTitle("my title");
    std::cout << w.getTitle();
}
```

Here is how you build it the library using g++

```
g++ WindowImp.cpp -std=c++11 -shared -o windowlibdll.dll -I Source\Repos\cppcomponents
```

And here is how you build with program using MSVC 2013

```
cl UseWindow.cpp /EHsc /I Source\Repos\cppcomponents
```

Replace `Source\Repose\cppcomponents` with the path were you have cppcomponents

Make sure the resulting windowslibdll.dll and the UseWindow.exe are in the same directory and run UseWindow.exe

Comment: Is it something like ATL implementation?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Kind-of. It uses modern c++11 techniques. ATL does not allow you to use standard types such as string or vector and does not allow exceptions. cppcomponents allows exceptions and strings, vectors. I will post an example of how to use in just a minute

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Example is up, let me know if you want a constructor that takes a string parameters and I will add to the example

Comment: Can I use function overloading?

Comment: Yes. It is transparent to use the overloaded functions, but you have to change the implementation a bit. Give me an example and I will show you how to do overloading

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40007/discussion-between-elvis-dukaj-and-john-bandela)

Comment: Does it work with ALL C++ features? Like virtual destructors and multiple inheritance? Can I wrap STL templates with it? Also what's the general idea behind it?